# Why does NIS map error prevent postfix from resolving local alias?

Tags: postfix, nis

Postfix quit sending me mail from an Ubuntu 10.04LTS server. I spent an hour to two checking `/etc/aliases`, running and re-running `sudo newaliases` and `sudo postfix reload`, web searches for my issue etc.

Sample log entry:

```
Dec  9 11:35:32 localhost postfix/local[1901]: warning: lookup owner-database, NIS domain nisdomain, map mail.aliases: no such map in server's domain
Dec  9 11:35:32 localhost postfix/local[1902]: B33FFACE000: to=<root@server9>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=833, delays=833/0.02/0/0.09, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (alias database unavailable)
```

I **am** using NIS and I **don't** have a `mail.aliases` map, but my `/etc/aliases` file is just fine. It should still work, right? Wrong.

It turns out that NIS was the problem. The `alias_maps` directive was set up by the installer in the commented-out line, removing the second entry fixed it.

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, nis:mail.aliases
```

change to

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
```

With the original line, my expectation is that Postfix would first look in `/etc/aliases`, then in `mail.aliases`. Anyone care to comment as to why postfix does/should fail to send at all instead of just the valid entry from `/etc/aliases`?

Answer (score 1):

Before performing alias lookup, postfix will check **all** database whether it is reachable or not.

Pseudocode

```
if all mapping was OK (file was found, external server was reachable)
    for each map in maps_array:
        if found in map
            return result
else 
    fail. give warning in maillog
```